# Symfony configuration useAttributeAsKey and indexed array

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I would like to create a Symfony Configuration class that takes the following YAML config:

```
bundle_name:
    section:
        attributeAsKey:
            - entry 1
            - entry 2
```

This would then yield an array like so:

```php
array(
   'section' => array(
      'attributeAsKey' => array(
          'entry1',
          'entry2'
       )
   )
)
```

I have tried the following, but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```php
->arrayNode('section')
    ->useAttributeAsKey('attributeAsKey')
    ->prototype('array')
        ->children()
            ->arrayNode('entries')
                ->prototype('scalar')->end()
            ->end()
        ->end()
    ->end()
->end()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I wound up doing...

```
            ->arrayNode('formats')
                ->useAttributeAsKey('format', true)
                ->prototype('array')
                ->beforeNormalization()
                    ->ifTrue(function ($v) { return is_array($v) && !isset($v['mimeTypes']); })
                    ->then(function ($v) { return array('mimeTypes' => $v); })
                ->end()
                    ->children()
                        ->arrayNode('mimeTypes')
                            ->prototype('scalar')->end()
                        ->end()
                    ->end()
                ->end()
            ->end()
```

The returning array has the 'mimeTypes' key, buit allows me to define the configuration like this:

```
formats:
    json:
        - application/json
        - application/x-json
        - application/vnd.lemon+json
```

As well as using the 'mimeTypes' key.